# Can I get the total number of test cases executed by maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project on which there are several sub-projects. Each sub-project has its own test cases and all of them are working fine. I want to know the number of test cases being executed on the parent project.

Is there anyway I can get the details of all the test cases executed? Even the number of test cases is also fine.

Kindly share your valuable inputs.

Comment: You can redirect the maven command output to a file and you can see the total no of test cases executed separately for each and every sub-project

Comment: Is there any command or maven property which will help answer the requirement?

Comment: Best is to run this within a CI solution like Jenkins where you get all this information...

Comment: Did you take a look to Maven surefire reports (https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/index.html) ?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do it as a one off you could first output the maven build to a log file:

```
mvn clean verify > maven_build.out
```

Then, you can run a bash one liner to sum up the number of tests run:

```
 echo $(( $(cat maven_build.out | grep "Tests run" | grep -v "Time elapsed" | cut -d , -f 1 | cut -d " " -f 3 | tr "\n" "+") 0))
```

This will extract all the 'Tests run' out of the log for each summary (as it is repeated), the number next to it, and sum it.

You'll need unix or cygwin

Comment: Depending on your version of maven and settings, sometimes the test counts to aggregate from the output of `cat maven_build.out | grep "Tests run" | grep -v "Time elapsed"` will be in the 4th column instead of the 3rd column. Just keep that in mind if you get an error such as `bad math expression: ':' without '?'`, try fixing the column being summed: `echo $(( $(cat maven_build_after.out | grep "Tests run" | grep -v "Time elapsed" | cut -d , -f 1 | cut -d " " -f 4 | tr "\n" "+") 0))`

Comment: Here is a similar solution using `awk` for the summation logic that will work depending on wether or not the test count is in the 3rd or 4th column (which varies depending on if log level is included in the maven output for test summaries):

`cat maven_build.out | grep "Tests run" | grep -v "Time elapsed" | awk -F' ' '{sum3+=$3;sum4+=$4} END{print sum3+sum4;}'`

Answer (score 2):

You can execute this simple bash script:

```
mvn test | egrep "^\[INFO\] Tests run: [0-9]+, Failures: [0-9]+, Errors: [0-9]+, Skipped: [0-9]+$" | egrep -o '[0-9]+' | awk '{n += $1}; END{print n}'
```

It calls Maven to run the test suite and redirects the output to `grep` to select test execution results. Then, `awk` counts the total of executed tests and prints the result to the standard output.

Comment: r u sure about that? i have a project that with this script gets 1.7 million tests

Comment: Add `^\[INFO\]`  to the regex of the first `egrep`

Comment: The script will not work if the Maven project doesn't finish to execute the tests. @Berto99 is the project open source?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to configure a listener in parent pom but am not sure how useful it would be.More information [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/testng-users/GC0GB1rnsuA)

Best solution is to configure build job in a continuous integration tool like Hudson.It can give you full information.