# Is there a way to fail a maven build if it finds tests to execute?

Tags: maven, testng

We ordered our tests into different quality gates, which we execute at a different time in our pipe.

What i am looking for, is a way to find tests, that do not have the group annotation of any quality gate. Basically i plan to create a new testng test suite which excludes the test groups of every other quality gate. If then there are still tests executed i want the build to fail. Is this possible? Are there simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once interesting solution is to create your extremely simple maven plugin that will:

1. Check the reports folder (surefire produces the `surefire-reports` folder) with files per test.
2. If it finds at least one file of tests - fail the build (throw an exception in the plugin).
3. Attach this plugin to the test phase right after the surefire and you're all set.

This is a purely maven solution.

Another solution can be testng specific.

I'm not a test ng expert, but you could create a listener on test execution that will actually fail the build in its methods. This listener will work only if you not running in the suite.

Comment: I second this, but would say that a custom enforcer rule (for the Maven enforcer plugin) may be even a better fit.

Comment: Not exactly what i asked, but this works as well in a jenkins pipeline script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41057547/7429320